# test list for membership and store only first true item + python

Tags: python, list

if i wanted to test a list for membership/match and store only the first true result how would i do it? should i use a set?

`list_test = ["adam", "ronny", "dave", "adam", "lisa", "lisa"]`

`list_test_for = ["adam", "lisa"]`

can i do this?

```
`for i in list_test:
     if i in list_test_for:
         new_set.Add(i.some operation)
```

will that keep it from duplicating? but also i want to make sure that i get only two items and not every time it sees a match.

desired output:

```
`new_set = ["adam".some operation, "lisa".some operation]
```

I want to make sure that i only get two items and in that order adam and lisa

Comment: What is the determining factor for the order of the result? The order in `list_test` or `list_test_for`? It's not clear from your example, since they are in the same order for both.

Comment: which list decides the order?

Comment: list_test_for is deciding order

Comment: why are you looping over `list_test` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_test = ["adam", "ronny", "dave", "adam", "lisa", "lisa"]
list_test_for = ["adam", "lisa"]

results = []

for name in list_test_for:
    try:
        results.append(next(match for match in list_test if name==match))
    except StopIteration:
        continue
```

Output:

results

```
['adam', 'lisa']
```

**EDIT:**

I found this method, which seems to work fine too:

```
results = [list_test[list_test.index(name)] for name in list_test_for]
```

Comment: yes, i think this will work. because now i can also do comparing if statement while doing another operation ex. if name==match.something

Comment: next is applied to the longest list, not the one with 2 elements.

Comment: He can use .index on the reference list as mentioned in my second solution, as .index also stops at the first match. But in the OPs case, I believe the "next" method is the way to go, as he needs to match some objects properties, and not only a single list value. But maybe the second method can also be leveraged.

Comment: Whatever. See it as another way of doing things. Both my solutions also work, don't they?

Comment: @Apero i agree with you and in this example i used two elements but normally i might use a lot more so thank you for the flexibility. Padraic please be nice man! :-) Apero was trying to help and i appreciate it. thank you to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the order you can use a list comprehension

```
>>> new_set = [i for i in list_test_for if i in list_test]
>>> new_set
['adam', 'lisa']
```

Otherwise, you could use `set.intersection`

```
>>> new_set = set(list_test_for).intersection(list_test)
>>> new_set
{'lisa', 'adam'}
```

Then you can iterate over `new_set` and do whatever you'd like to each member. For example if I wanted to find the length of each string in `new_set` I could say

```
>>> list(map(len, new_set))
[4, 4]
```

Comment: He stated that order is relevant - so sets won't do the trick.